# Scalatest + maven

Tags: scala, maven, junit, scalatest

I am trying to use scalatest to test a class. This is the test I am trying to run:

```
    @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class CategorizationSpec extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter with Matchers{
  var ss:SparkSession = _
  before{
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7");
    val conf = new SparkConf(true)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost")
      .set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true")
      .set("spark.executor.memory","4g")
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    ss =  SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("categorization")
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()
    ss.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost")


  }

  "DictionaryPerUser" should "be empty" in {
    val dpuc=new DictionaryPerUserController(ss)
    dpuc.truncate()
    dpuc.getDictionary shouldBe null
  }
}
```

but I get the following error:

> [ERROR] /path/project/datasystem/CategorizationSpec.scala:3: error: object controllers is not a member of package path.project.datasystem
>   [ERROR] import path.project.datasystem.controllers.DictionaryPerUserController

But I have that class in /src/main/scala/path/project and the test class is in /src/test/scala/path/project

Do you know any idea?

Comment: how is your pom setup?

Comment: If you solved the issue, you should post the solution as an answer and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Solved, sorry it was a problem in my pom!